# C# dictionary add values array

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, multidimensional-array, indexing

I want to add an array with 3 values to the value of an dictionary. For example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, ComputeNTree>();
dict.Add(1, new ComputeNTree(12, 1, 0));
dict.Add(1, new ComputeNTree(14, 2, 0));
dict.Add(2, new ComputeNTree(16, 4, 0));
public class ComputeNTree
{
   public ComputeNTreeIndexes[] ComputeNTreeIndexes
}
public class ComputeNTreeIndexes
{
    public int IdCategory { get; set; }
    public int Nleft { get; set; }
    public int Nright { get; set; }
}
```

It's possible for me to declare the amount of indexes at an existing key but if it's possible to add values to a certain key and it's associated array, that's no problem.

Edit: I want to translate some pieces of code from prestashop to c#:

```
public static function regenerateEntireNtree()
    {
        $id = Context::getContext()->shop->id;
        $idShop = $id ? $id : Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_DEFAULT');
        $sql = new DbQuery();
        $sql->select('c.`id_category`, c.`id_parent`');
        $sql->from('category', 'c');
        $sql->leftJoin('category_shop', 'cs', 'c.`id_category` = cs.`id_category` AND cs.`id_shop` = ' . (int) $idShop);
        $sql->orderBy('c.`id_parent`, cs.`position` ASC');
        $categories = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
        $categoriesArray = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $categoriesArray[$category['id_parent']]['subcategories'][] = $category['id_category'];
        }
        
        $n = 1;

        if (isset($categoriesArray[0]) && $categoriesArray[0]['subcategories']) {
            $queries = Category::computeNTreeInfos($categoriesArray, $categoriesArray[0]['subcategories'][0], $n);

            // update by batch of 5000 categories
            $chunks = array_chunk($queries, 5000);
            foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
                $sqlChunk = array_map(function ($value) { return '(' . rtrim(implode(',', $value)) . ')'; }, $chunk);
                Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category` (id_category, nleft, nright)
                VALUES ' . rtrim(implode(',', $sqlChunk), ',') . '
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nleft=VALUES(nleft), nright=VALUES(nright)');
            }
        }
    }

protected static function computeNTreeInfos(&$categories, $idCategory, &$n)
    {
        $queries = array();
        $left = $n++;
        if (isset($categories[(int) $idCategory]['subcategories'])) {
            foreach ($categories[(int) $idCategory]['subcategories'] as $idSubcategory) {
                $queries = array_merge($queries, Category::computeNTreeInfos($categories, (int) $idSubcategory, $n));
            }
        }
        $right = (int) $n++;

        $queries[] = array($idCategory, $left, $right);

        return $queries;
    }
```

It's the last function which I am struggling with and that part was my question.

Thanks!
Paul

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, its probably useful to show an example of what you want

Comment: Agree, it's really hard to get what you want.

Comment: Yes I know, let me tell you the whole story. I am trying to translate a part of prestashop's php code to c#. This function sets the left and right numbers according to the categories. I'll edit my question and add the code...

Comment: you can try GroupBy of LINQ maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume your goal is to have a dictionary that is a `<int, List<ComputeNTree>>` pair, as what I was able to understand by your code in:

```
dict.Add(1, new ComputeNTree(12, 1, 0));
dict.Add(1, new ComputeNTree(14, 2, 0));
dict.Add(2, new ComputeNTree(16, 4, 0));
```

In this sense, you should use the Key as an accessor to a list.
Initialize the dictionary with the `int` keys you need. You will also have to create code to check whether a key exists or not. Add a new key and remove a key if that functionality is necessary.

In order to add new elements to your list in a certain dictionary pair. Retrieve the List from the pair. As simply as

```
var list = dict[key];
```

From there you can operate as you normally would with C# lists.

```
list.add(new ComputeNTree(16,4,0);
```

So instead of `dict.Add()` you will need to implement these methods. Checking if the key exists and has an initialized list and go from there.